# Need to fetch both Columns in XML Nodes?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to get the 'A' and 'B' Columns in the **Same(Single)** `SELECT` Statement **instead of using the 2 `SELECT`** Statements:

Tried query:

```
DECLARE @Invoice_Types  VARCHAR(MAX)='T-E,T-I,3-E,D-E,D-I'
,@Invoice_TypesXML XML

SET @Invoice_TypesXML=CAST(('<I>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(@Invoice_Types,',','</R><I>'),'-' ,'</I><R>') +'</R>') 
AS XML);

SELECT I.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') A                        
FROM @Invoice_TypesXML.nodes('I') AS FN(I)

SELECT R.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') B                       
FROM @Invoice_TypesXML.nodes('R') AS FN(R)
```

Expected Result: in **Single `Select` Statement**

```
 A   B
-----------------
T   E
T   I
3   E
D   E
D   I
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirement, you need to revise your XML structure like this:

```
    <Item>
          <I>T</I><R>E</R>
   </Item>
    <Item>
          <I>T</I><R>I</R>
   </Item>
    <Item>
          <I>3</I><R>E</R>
   </Item>
    <Item>
          <I>D</I><R>E</R>
   </Item>
    <Item>
          <I>D</I><R>I</R>
   </Item>
```

And then you can select your final result in one select statement.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @Invoice_Types  VARCHAR(MAX)='T-E,T-I,3-E,D-E,D-I'
,@Invoice_TypesXML XML

SET @Invoice_TypesXML=CAST(('<Item><I>'+REPLACE(REPLACE(@Invoice_Types,',','</R></Item><Item><I>'),'-' ,'</I><R>') +'</R></Item>') 
AS XML);


SELECT 
    x.Rec.query('./I').value('.', 'nvarchar(2000)') AS 'A',
    x.Rec.query('./R').value('.', 'nvarchar(2000)') AS 'B'
FROM @Invoice_TypesXML.nodes('/Item') as x(Rec)
```

Final result:

```
A   B
_____
T   E
T   I
3   E
D   E
D   I
```

See this [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=703414d176641c2ac4e831d5401e2a5d)

Answer (score 0):

One solution is :

```
SELECT I.value('(I[1])', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') A, I.value('(R[1])', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') B                       
FROM @Invoice_TypesXML.nodes('.') AS FN(I)
UNION ALL
SELECT I.value('(I[2])', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') A, I.value('(R[2])', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') B                       
FROM @Invoice_TypesXML.nodes('.') AS FN(I)
UNION ALL
...
```

More generically :

```
WITH 
TI AS
(
SELECT I.value('(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') I, row_number() over(order by I) AS N
FROM @Invoice_TypesXML.nodes('I') AS FN(I)
),
TR AS
(
SELECT I.value('(.)', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') R, row_number() over(order by I) AS N 
FROM @Invoice_TypesXML.nodes('R') AS FN(I)
)
SELECT I, R
FROM   TI JOIN TR ON TI.N = TR.N
```